# Command-line completion from command history

Tags: bash, command-history, autocomplete

So, I've looked at history and at <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, but they are not what I thought I knew.
Is there a way that I can type in the beginning of a command, and cycle through the matches in my history with some bash shortcut?

```
# mysq(some shortcut key)
```

Gives me:

```
# mysqldump  --add-drop-table -e -q -n -C -u 
(some shortcut key)
#  mysql -u ben.dauphinee -p
```

Comment: Side note: There is '<kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd>' for tty's without desktop.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> will open the reverse history search. Now start typing your command, this will give the first match.
By pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> again (and again) you can cycle through the history.

```
mysq(Ctrl+R)
```

Would give:

```
mysqldump  --add-drop-table -e -q -n -C -u
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> again:

```
mysql -u ben.dauphinee -p
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, Esc will put the selected command on your command line without executing, while Enter will run the selected command.

Comment: I find CTRL+E better for this than ESC, because escape is awkward to reach for but I am already hitting CTRL+R, so E is right there. This also positions the cursor at the end of the line, which is handy in case I wanted to change something (like a file name) which I find to be a common case.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work on Cygwin

Comment: On mac, at least, it seems `mysq(CTRL+R)(CTRL+R)` doesn't cycle through commands beginning with "mysq".  You need to do `(CTRL+R)mysq(CTRL+R)` instead

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I have Bash setup on Windows 10 and that's how it works there as well.  Took me a second to figure out how it was working.

Answer (score 101):

To expand on what Gilles said, I have the following in my `.inputrc` to bind the up/down arrow key to `history-search-backward` and `history-search-forward`:

```
# Key bindings, up/down arrow searches through history
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\eOA": history-search-backward
"\eOB": history-search-forward
```

Just type something (optional), then press up/down arrow key to search through history for commands that begin with what you typed.

To do this in `.bashrc` rather than `.inputrc`, you can use:

```
bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'
```

Comment: those binding belong into ~/.inputrc ...thanks for supporting my lazyness.

Comment: It is worth noting that the '\e' is crucial, at least for bash debutants. Just typing Ctrl-V to get the keystroke for your command doesn't tell the whole story. For example, typing Ctrl-V Meta-P (i.e.) Alt-P) returns ^[p -- to get the behavior you want, replace the "^[" with '\e'.

Comment: Agree with @syslogic -- put the lines in .inputrc and drop the bind and single quotes.

Comment: copy-pasting this into .inputrc on osx, i get : source ~/.inputrc
-bash: \e[A:: command not found
-bash: \e[B:: command not found
-bash: \eOA:: command not found
-bash: \eOB:: command not found

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/241187/how-do-i-reload-inputrc. You can't source the file.

Comment: To get this to work in your current shell, run `bind -f ~/.inputrc`

Comment: I think this is the nicer solution. Thank you @raychi

Answer (score 10):

You could also press the `PAGEUP` button to auto-complete a command. It basically searches the `bash_history` file.

Comment: You have to uncomment two lines in `/etc/inputrc` or add these two lines to your `$HOME/.inputrc` file: 
```"\e[5~": history-search-backward
"\e[6~": history-search-forward```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the readline commands `history-search-backward` and `history-search-forward` to navigate between commands lines beginning with the prefix you've already typed. Neither of these commands are bound to keys in the default configuration.

Zsh (zle) has similar commands `history-beginning-search-backward` and `history-beginning-search-forward`, also not bound to keys by default. There are also `history-search-backward` and `history-search-forward`, which uses the first word of the current command as the prefix to search regardless of the cursor position.

Answer (score 7):

If you want a good overview of very similar commands you can get a list with:

```
history|grep KEYSTRING
```

Then copy and paste with the middle button of your mouse.

Rgds - Joe