# Search bash history for already typed command

Tags: bash, shell, autocomplete, command-history

When I type ctrl+r and *then* start typing I can see what commands in the history match which is great.

Now is there a way to search the history on commands I have *already* typed in the terminal?

For example if I type ctrl+r and then type ping I can cycle through servers I have pinged. But if I type "ping" first and then hit ctrl+r it ignores the "ping" I have already typed.

Some times I'll get half way though typing out a string of commands and then think "oh I already typed this it sure would be nice to search the history on what I have already typed instead of starting over".

Does this make sense what I am asking?

Comment: ctrl-r doesn't complete the commands from history - only searches. I think what you're looking for is a ctrl-r + tab completion kind of thing. Don't think there is one.

Comment: I've added an answer here to address the issue that I also happen to do a lot. This other stackexchange site has more tips: https://superuser.com/questions/384051/is-there-a-way-of-using-ctrl-r-after-typing-part-of-command-in-bash

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you start typing a command and then, after typing some of it, remember to do a history search, you just need to:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> **...** (keep searching or)
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> **...** (search in the other direction*)

---

Note: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> will suspend your terminal unless you explicitly revoked this behavior with

`[[ $- == *i* ]] && stty -ixon`

in your `.bashrc`

---

Edited: a shortcut can be seen here in this somewhat duplicated question https://superuser.com/questions/384051/is-there-a-way-of-using-ctrl-r-after-typing-part-of-command-in-bash/1271740#1271740

Answer (score 7):

The answer is in one of the "Related" questions listed automatically by stackexchange in the right-hand column. To experiment type

```
bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'
```

then type your partial command and use up-arrow key (which should generate `escape [ A`) to search for this partial input in your history.  See the [full answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20830/119298) for more.